# C++ Print formatted data either to std::cout or to a file (buffered)

Tags: c++, file, logging

I have been using [Petru's logging framework](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/201804215?pgno=1) a bit. This is part of his code:

```
class Output2FILE
{
public:
  static FILE*& Stream() {
    static FILE* pStream = stderr;
    return pStream;
  }
};
```

Which is very nice as it simply logs to stderr without any action, but with the function that can afterwards be set to anything including stdout and a file. However, I think this approach can't be used for formatted data as one needs to use fprintf.

Hence I am trying to come up with something similar that lets one use stdout by default and that can be switched to a file, but using the "<<" operator for formatted data.

Maybe something along the lines of

```
std::ostream myOutput(std::cout);
```

with the idea of then doing `myOutput << "Hello" << 1 << 1.5;`. Above line however makes the compiler complain though.

What is the correct way?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK streams are not copyable

Comment: Cheers Armen that leads to the simple answer really. `std::ostream& myOutput(std::cout);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pointer to an `std::ostream` much like the `FILE*` version.

```
std::ostream* os = &std::cerr;
if (log_to_file) {
  os = new std::ofstream("my.log");
}

*os << "Hello Log!" << std::endl;

if (log_to_file) { // or less 'safe' os != &std::cerr ...
    // close file here
}
```

Comment: Indeed. Or even a reference, that saves dereference on output lines.

Comment: I was going to suggest this at first, but with pointers you have the option of retargeting at runtime - for example if creating the log file fails.

Comment: True. I have actually just run into problems trying to work with a global reference. Looks like a pointer does make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer, really

```
std::ostream& myOutput(std::cout);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understood correctly what you're looking for. But it seems as if this one could help you:

```
#include <sstream>

#define SSTR( x ) ( dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >( \
            ( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()
```

Usage:

```
SSTR( "Hello" << 1 << 1.5 );
```

Yields std::string (which you can then feed to whatever output function you want).

Elaborate description and explanation: http://dev.rootdirectory.de/trac.fcgi/wiki/SSTR%28%29